# Populate field onLoad Social feed SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, user-profile, form

I am trying to auto populate user Email, Name, Title on a SharePoint form.

I can see the values when I inspect the page (F12) but they don't appear on the form `onLoad`.

I can obtain the input fields id via the developer tool, not 100% sure I am using the correct ID.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(function () {
   getUserProfileInfo();   
});

function getUserProfileInfo() {

var fullUrl = "https://sites/sites/dome/_api/social.feed/my";

$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: onUserInfoQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
});
}

function onUserInfoQuerySucceeded(data) {
  var userInfoItemE = data.d.Me.EmailAddress;
  var userInfoItemN = data.d.Me.Name;
  var userInfoItemT = data.d.Me.Title;    

  document.getElementById('Email_a6570af6-8b72-4ab0-814d-93f50f26e185_$TextField').innerHTML = userInfoItemE;
  document.getElementById('Name_b6023c0f-43be-45b4-b946-22ac2933bb77_$TextField').innerHTML = userInfoItemN;
  document.getElementById('Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField').innerHTML = userInfoItemT;
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('Email_a6570af6-8b72-4ab0-814d-93f50f26e185_$TextField').innerHTML = userInfoItemE;
```

try

```
document.getElementById('Email_a6570af6-8b72-4ab0-814d-93f50f26e185_$TextField').value= userInfoItemE;
```

**Explanation**

`innerHTML` is supposed to manage the child HTML elements. In your case, it procudes invalid HTML. `< input >` is not supposed to have child elements.

Instead, you want to update `value` attribute of the `input`